# Ajax error when i try to load my JqueryDataTable

Tags: json, datatables

I try to get my Json here: "https://www.suale.it/Pet/scriptWS.aspx?func=caricaDatatable&Lat=0&lon=0" with JSONP (who capture it as a < script src to bypass CORS)
When it try to load my jquery Datatable  (named 'example' here) it gives error, and i dont have any clue to understand what happened.
I also tried to validate my json with https://jsonlint.com/, it is valid!
I need help to understand better whats wrong

```js
          
  function clickButton() {
    //var obj, s
    //obj = { table: "products", limit: 10 };
    s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "https://www.suale.it/Pet/scriptWS.aspx?func=LoadDataTable&Lat=0&lon=0"
    
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }
  
 
 function LoadDataTable(data)
 {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": JSON.stringify(data),
        "columns": [
            { "data": "titolo" },
            { "data": "Lat" },
            { "data": "lon" }
        ]
    } );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



 <p id="demo"></p>

 
   <input type=button onclick="clickButton()" value="prova">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>titolo</th>
                <th>Lat</th>
                <th>lon</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>titolo</th>
                <th>Lat</th>
                <th>lon</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Datatables Data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option instead of Ajax cause you load it from your updated DOM/Javascript.

When datasource is in object, we can use Datatables [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) to map with your data object key. So your `data : objkey` must match and correct.

```
function LoadDataTable(data)
    {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Titolo" },
            { "data": "Latitudine" },
            { "data": "Longitudine" }
        ]
    } );
    }
```

**Modified working demo:**

```js
var dataSet = [{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null},{"Titolo":"colonia di formiche","Latitudine":"-33.905635","Longitudine":"151.195331","Icona":"/ICO0.jpg","HTML":null}];

function clickButton() {
/*
I've to comment this and copied response data to dataset variable, so this demo will always working even when the original link dissappeared in future
/*
/*
    s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "https://www.suale.it/Pet/scriptWS.aspx?func=LoadDataTable&Lat=0&lon=0"

    document.body.appendChild(s);
*/
      LoadDataTable(dataSet);
}

function LoadDataTable(data)
 {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Titolo" },
            { "data": "Latitudine" },
            { "data": "Longitudine" }
        ]
    } );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type=button onclick="clickButton()" value="prova">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>titolo</th>
                <th>Lat</th>
                <th>lon</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>titolo</th>
                <th>Lat</th>
                <th>lon</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```